# Using method="nls" to plot 3 parameter Weibull curve

Tags: r, ggplot2, nls, weibull

I would like to plot several 3 parameter Weibull curves with the function y ~ m*exp(-1*(x/b)^c).
In most cases I could define the starting parameters and plot the curves using nls2 and ggplot2. However, I fail to plot one particular curve  in ggplot2 (I could fit the curves using nls2 though).

It is important to me to use the the `method="nls"` command in `ggplot` (and not loess, the latter tends to overfit the curves in many cases).
Could anyone help me with this? Much appreciated!

```
    #Load packages
library(ggplot2)
library(nlme)
library(nls2)
# library(proto)

#model structure: 3 parameter Weibull
#y ~ m*exp(-1*(x/b)^c)

dip3dta<-structure(list(ploidy = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("dip", "trp"), class = "factor"), 
                        geno = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                           3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("dip1", "dip2", "dip3", "dip4", "dip5", 
                                                                   "dip6", "dip7", "dip8", "trp1", "trp2", "trp3", "trp4", "trp5", 
                                                                   "trp6", "trp7", "trp8"), class = "factor"), Photo = c(10.03907124, 
                                                                                                                         16.04016877, 5.799933798, 6.256058037, 1.34916505, 9.609508391, 
                                                                                                                         12.84023945, 8.436093321, 7.732332332, 15.38729611, 2.157795186, 
                                                                                                                         5.93553951, 3.37322132), WBPhoto = c(11.77970983, 13.52705488, 
                                                                                                                                                              7.585920181, 6.118582453, 2.570461685, 10.80358492, 9.445462376, 
                                                                                                                                                              5.386306724, 5.840252952, 15.84494637, 3.60398487, 9.32456564, 
                                                                                                                                                              3.437440219), PDLWP = c(3.1, 2.6, 5.8, 7.7, 19, 3.5, 4.25, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      9, 8.16, 2.25, 13.92, 4.33, 14.58), Treatment = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "DC", class = "factor")), row.names = 27:39, class = "data.frame")

#Define the outer boundaries to search for initial values
grddip3 <- data.frame(m=c(0,45),
                      b=c(0,8),
                      cc=c(0,0.6))

#Brute-force initial values
fitdip3 <- nls2(Photo ~ m*exp(-1*(PDLWP/b)^cc),
                data=dip3dta,
                start = grddip3,
                algorithm = "brute-force")
fitdip3
finalfitdip3 <- nls(Photo ~ m*exp(-1*(PDLWP/b)^cc),
                    data=dip3dta,
                    start=as.list(coef(fitdip3)),
                    algorithm = "port",
                    lower = coef(fitdip3)/1000,
                    control=list(maxiter=1000))
```

The above code works fine but I can't plot the curve in ggplot using `method="nls"`

```
# Plot in ggplot
exampledip3<-ggplot(dip3dta, aes(x=PDLWP,y=Photo)) + geom_point(size=2)+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=18),
        axis.title=element_text(size=17,),axis.title.y=element_text(margin=margin(0,20,0,0)))+
  stat_smooth(method = "nls", formula = y ~ m*exp(-1*(x/b)^c), size = 0.9, se = FALSE, colour = "black")
```

Comment: You can always extract the fitted values from the model (use broom::augment) and plot these with geom_line

Comment: Pass better starting values to nls within ggplot2?

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. I actually already possess all the fitted values. So if there is a way to plot the fitted values using the equation for the 3-parameter Weibull, I would be more than happy. However, when using "geom_line" I can't sepcificy the "method=nls" or the formula = y ~ m*exp(-1*(x/b)^c). So in some cases geom_line will just produce a zig-zag "curve" rather than a typical sigmoid curve. 
Is there a way to plot my already fitted values as a 3-parameter weibull in ggplot?